# segue.destinationViewController - NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When a user selects a row in UITableViewController, I want to segue to another viewController and set its UIImageView to a previously set image. For now, I am making it generic - always show /images/en.jpeg.

flickrTVC.m (UITableViewController):

```
@implementation flickrTVC

...

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPhoto"])
        UIImage *photo = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"images/en.jpeg"];
        [segue.destinationViewController setDisplayedPhoto:photo];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showPhoto" sender:self];
}
```

I have *-(void)setDisplayedPhoto:(UIImage *)image;* (it sets self.photo to image) in my photoViewController.h (segue.destinationViewController).
I am getting

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController setDisplayedPhoto:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f5c4a60'
```

on the following line: *[segue.destinationViewController setDisplayedPhoto:photo];*. Even with the implementation blank, the error still shows up.
I am new to objective-c and, probably, I am just messing some things up.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception occurs because the object that was there does not define the method `setDisplayedPhoto:`.  This could be because the `segue.destinationViewController` is currently set to a completely different controller (e.g. for a different view than you think).  It could also be that you've defined something similar to that method but not exactly the same; if so then the compiler has probably issued a warning about the `setDisplayedPhoto:` method call.

Comment: Newbie mistake... I did not change the ViewController's class from generic to photoViewController! Thanks for a rapid response, I appreciate it!